# Versión de laravel recomendada

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día a todos, tengo una confusión.

Necesito crear un proyecto en laravel pero el servidor solo funciona con versiones de php <=5.6 que versión de laravel es compatible con esa versión de php, también para la ejecución de un proyecto de laravel en local, es necesario cambiar la versión php que tiene por defecto que tengo instalada en el servidor local por la versión 5.6. Lo anterior es para evitar problemas cuando ya se suba el proyecto al servidor web.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda y espero que la pregunta halla sido lo mas clara posible.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: y la documentacion de laravel no aclara eso?

Comment: En la documentación, en la sección de los requisitos de servidor te indica por versión que nesitas tener instalado, al momento tu versión de PHP es el problema por que no solo esta abandonada (*con todo lo que esto implica*) sino que además [esta será la máxima versión de Laravel que podrás usar](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements) y ya vamos en la versión 7

Comment: Deberías actualizar tu versión de PHP cuanto antes, no veo razón válida para que uses un PHP tan viejo, revisa esto: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php